# Use of should in the sentence provided

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, should, language-formation

I don't understand what is the use of "should" in this sentence:- "Strange that now in its old age this dark business *should* have cast its shadow upon the venerable walls!"

Comment: [*It's funny you should say that*,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=funny+you+should+say+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfunny%20you%20should%20say%20that%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfunny%20you%20should%20say%20that%3B%2Cc0) but the usage is definitely on the up & up.

Comment: ...but I can't see why we don't seem to be able to say *It's **rude** you should say that* (only constructions like *It's rude **of you to say** that* seem to work there).

Answer (score 1):

Especially in UK English *should* might be substituted for *would* in its modal verb form.

cambridge.org/dictionary/english/should